# Añadir valores en una nueva columna

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

he creado una nueva columna llamada *'precio'* pero no sé cómo añadirle datos.

La tabla que creé al inicio:

```
TABLE peliculas(
idpelicula varchar(2) PRIMARY KEY,
titulo varchar(60),
genero varchar(2),
calificacion int,
duracion time,
subtitulos set('español','ingles','frances','aleman');
```

**Valores añadidos:**

```
INSERT INTO peliculas VALUES
('02','Di que si','01',7,020318),
('03','Malavita','01',12,015133,'frances'),
('04','Scarface','05',18,021421,'ingles'),
('05','Hermano oso','06',3,014634,'español,aleman'),
('06','Cars','06',3,015716,'español,frances,ingles'),
('07','Medianoche en Paris','10',12,021548,'frances,ingles');
```

**El nuevo campo que he creado:**

```
ALTER TABLE peliculas
ADD COLUMN (precio int);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día unanobot, de primer instancia te recomiendo utilizar el precio de tipo float, esto en caso de que uno de tus precios pueda contar con centavos, es decir, precio FLOAT(10,2).

Continuando con el tema, tendrías que realizar un UPDATE a cada registro de tu tabla.

p.e:

```
UPDATE peliculas SET precio = 10 WHERE peliculas.idpelicula = '02';
UPDATE peliculas SET precio = 12 WHERE peliculas.idpelicula = '03';
```

Comment: De hecho para precios lo indicado es Decimal pues ofrece más exactitud

Comment: Bien con la respuesta @Eliseo, asimismo quisiera acotar que es mejor preguntar al **OP** sobre el `int en precio` ya que depende del país, algunos no usan decimales o centavos, ejemplo de ello Colombia trabaja en [Pesos Colombianos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peso_(moneda_de_Colombia))

Comment: Sí, ya he comprobado y funciona perfectamente; había visto en otros sitios que usaban insert into nombre_tabla(nombre_columna) values, aunque no me funcionaba. Con el tema del precio, sería un float efectivamente, ha sido un fallo mío.